# How do I configure my wireless settings for a particular network if all I have are instructions for Windows?

Tags: wireless, pptp, certificates, wpa2

I've been trying to connect to my university's secure wireless network, unfortunately they only provide instructions for Windows users [here](http://remedy4.ars.unt.edu:8080/rkm/viewdoc.jsp?doc=395&type=?&user=Self%20Help). I've tried to use the info on these instructions as best I can but I have not been successful. In particular, I think the problem might be with the certificate part. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: The OSX instructions might be better - http://remedy4.ars.unt.edu:8080/rkm/viewdoc.jsp?doc=326&sid=10538&type=Published&terms=quick_searchTerms&user=Self%20Help  Network Name: eaglenet
Security: None

Comment: @arochester That's for the unencrypted network (goes through a portal) and I wouldn't suggest that if you don't want to get various online accounts hacked (session stealing, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the I had to go past the first level of computer support but they actually did help me out. The only problem was that I needed to choose an AddTrust CA instead of a GeoTrust CA, even though you need to choose GeoTrust if you're in Windows. Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually all fairly simple. There's [a similar guide at Michigan U for Ubuntu](http://www.engin.umich.edu/caen/network/wireless/old/linux.html) shows the whole process. Network Manager should do most of the heavy lifting. You might need to select the encryption type (PEAP).

Other than that, [talk to your support people](http://www.unt.edu/helpdesk/wireless/). This is what they're paid almost nothing to help with :)

Comment: I tried a [similar guide](http://www.lug.wsu.edu/wireless/peap/ubuntu), adjusting it to my network's specifications. The two main changes I made were using the “GeoTrust Global CA” certificate which I obtained [here](http://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/index.html) and setting "Inner Authentication" as GTC instead of MSCHAPv2. The instructions for Windows computers instruct us to use EAP-Token instead of MSCHAPv2. Still no luck.

Comment: That's what I would have done so that's me out of suggestions. Have a chat with the technical support people. The encryption protocols might be a little beyond them but they should be able to talk to somebody to give you instruction. And you should suggest they add it to their KB.

Comment: I'll give tech support a call but usually they just shun linux users. Could using a different network manager (such as WICD) possibly make a difference?

Comment: @user87317 I strongly doubt it.